# ClosedXML Worksheet from DataTable isn't following Culture

Tags: c#, excel, datatable, closedxml

When I add a worksheet via a `DataTable`, I would expect the date formats to follow the locale/culture of the application but it appears to take that from the computer.

```
string culture = "en-GB";
var newCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = newCulture; //probably unnecessary?
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = newCulture;

// ... select myDateColumn, myIntCol, myString
workBook.AddWorksheet(myDataTableThatContainsQueryResults, tabName);
```

Now, you'd expect the first column (`myDateColumn`) to format using the short date format of the `en-GB` locale which should be `'31/10/2017'` but it's coming out as `'10/31/2017'` instead.

I checked the locale in the DataTable once I get it back from the SQLDataAdapter and it's correct as are the nested date formats. Note that there are multiple queries and I won't know where the dates are in advance.

Appreciate any direction someone can provide!

Answer (score 3):

I don't have the reputation to comment...

By looking at a few tests on the ClosedXML github repo, it appears that the library expects the culture to be set before instantiating the workbook.
(https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML/blob/c2d408b127844ea3d4a5f6b060c548c953b6bcf3/ClosedXML_Tests/Excel/CalcEngine/LookupTests.cs#L17)

```
    private XLWorkbook workbook;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Init()
    {
        // Make sure tests run on a deterministic culture
        System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
        workbook = SetupWorkbook();
    }
```

It is unclear to me from your question if that is the case in your code.

If that is already the case, you should open a bug @ ClosedXML on Github.

Comment: Are you trying to use multiple cultures per workbook based on the SQLAdapter results? Don't know if ClosedXml would support that... (would need more code digging)

Comment: No, I'm using a single culture for the whole workbook.  It's being set before we instantiate the new workbook.

Comment: @ArisBerard Did you manage to find a workaround for your issue?